How do I suspend a specific thread within a process, like an application?
Title says all, I would like to find out how to do this via command prompt or batch. if you find out how, please feel free to post below.
I already tried multiple methods online via microsoft documentation.

You can call SuspendThread, but i think no way do this via some built-in command
